# how to reproduce an action on all the members of a list to write an "importrange" command from multiple http links

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'am trying to import a lot of Googlesheet into 1 using the "=importrange" command and a script.
here is so far where I'am getting stuck :

I have been able to do the code to import 1 sheet, but when it comes to import and deal with  2 or more sheets, I'am no longer able to "iterate" my actions.

here is an example with 3 http links of what I want to write into the box :

```
=QUERY({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZvgM-rTpHJbBJB-F6iqtSE7NB5Jdl-_Q7LQL_ELhLo8?authuser=design%40wearemakers.fr&usp=drive_fs","'TOTAUX'!A3:C");importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SH9iY55UEm9glHXfgFD2bpMCcDaQMChS8nsH_0SJ6RA?authuser=design%40wearemakers.fr&usp=drive_fs","'TOTAUX'!A3:C");https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SH9iY55UEm9glHXfgFD2bpMCcDaQMChS8nsH_0SJ6RA/edit?usp=drivesdk","'TOTAUX'!A3:C")}, "Select * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")
```

here is what the code produce actually :

```
=QUERY({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/174wJ6l1ohnYKxaKEQLjOiCprc1bwqlY0dougaLZqOs4/edit?usp=drivesdk,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZvgM-rTpHJbBJB-F6iqtSE7NB5Jdl-_Q7LQL_ELhLo8/edit?usp=drivesdk,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SH9iY55UEm9glHXfgFD2bpMCcDaQMChS8nsH_0SJ6RA/edit?usp=drivesdk,,,,,,,,,","'TOTAUX'!A3:C")}, "Select * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")
```

And here the code :

````
  var COLsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COLLECTEUR");
  var link = COLsheet.getRange(2,9,COLsheet.getMaxRows()).getValues();
  var plage = "'TOTAUX'!A3:C";
  var imp  = 'importrange("' + (link)+ '";"' + (plage) + '")';
  var que = '=QUERY({' + (imp) + '}, "Select * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")';


/**
  for (var i in link) {
  var links = link[i];
}**/


  Logger.log(link)
  //Logger.log(links)

  COLsheet.getRange('D5').setValues([[que]]);

} ```


I have try to do something with[i], but I just don't really know what to do...
````

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var COLsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COLLECTEUR");
  var link = COLsheet.getRange(2, 9, COLsheet.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().filter(([i]) => i);
  var plage = "'TOTAUX'!A3:C";
  var imp = link.map(([i]) => `importrange("${i}";"${plage}")`);
  var que = `=QUERY({${imp.join(";")}},"Select * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")`;
  COLsheet.getRange('D5').setFormula(que);
}
```

- When this script is run, when the values of `link` are the valid Spreadsheet URLs, `que` becomes as follows.

  ```
    =QUERY({
      importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit","'TOTAUX'!A3:C");
      importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit","'TOTAUX'!A3:C");
      importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit","'TOTAUX'!A3:C");
      ;
      ;
      ;
    },"Select * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")
  ```
- In the case of `var link = COLsheet.getRange(2,9,COLsheet.getMaxRows()).getValues()`, the values are retrieved from all rows. So, I modified to `var link = COLsheet.getRange(2, 9, COLsheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([i]) => i)`.
- In this modification, the template literal was used.
- In order to create the formula of `importrange`, I used `map`.

#### References:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String))